# Bootstrap CSS Navigation overlapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Having a problem with bootstrap Nav bar when displayed on phone. The compressed element kicks in and the two different Nav bars overlap:

Two rows of navigation and both have collapsing menus.

See screen shot from both iPad and iPhone.

Edit:
After example provided:
[image]

[image: ipad]

[image: iphone]

[image: overlapping menu]

```
   <!-- navbar -->
 <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Computer Medic</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../../database_code/database_code.php">Database Code</a>       </li>
                    <li><a href="../../../projects/projects.php">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../../bookmarks/bookmarks.php">Bookmarks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../../notes/notes.php">Notes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->



    <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- to enable navigation dropdown when viewed in mobile device -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Change "Site Admin" to your site name -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>admin/index.php">CM Site Admin</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


            <!-- highlight for order related pages -->
            <li <?php echo $page_title=="Admin Index" ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>admin/index.php">Home</a>
            </li>

            <!-- highlight for user related pages -->
            <li <?php
                    echo $page_title=="Users"
                        || $page_title=="Create User"
                        || $page_title=="Update User"
                        || $page_title=="User Search Results"
                        || $page_title=="Change Password"
                        || strip_tags($page_title)=="Users / Edit User"
                        || strip_tags($page_title)=="Users / Create User"
                        ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> >
                <a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>admin/read_users.php">Users</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- options in the upper right corner of the page -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <!-- update currently logged in admin user -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $home_url . "admin/update_user.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">Edit Profile</a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- change password -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $home_url . "admin/change_password.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">Change Password</a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- log out user -->
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

</div>
 </div>
 <!-- /navbar -->
```

Comment: There are no screenshots in your question and what exactly are you trying to do? At the least overlapping will happen from adding `navbar-fixed-top`.

Comment: Only overlaps in small screen

Comment: I see the one with `navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top` overlap the lower one on screens @ 768px and up, then below 768px that toggle menu overlaps both menus when clicked. **Again what are you trying to do?** Have two separate `navbars` that both toggle when individually clicked or what exactly?

Comment: Yes have two nav bars that toggle when clicked.

Comment: Also both toggles seem to produce the inverse bar results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do.

You can enclose two individual navbars inside a single `.navbar-fixed-top` so they maintain individual classes as far as the styling differences while remaining in a fixed position with no overlap: `navbar-default` and `navbar-inverse`. Then just make sure each has there own unique `data-target` for the individual toggles to function.

**For example:**

```
data-target="#navbar1" with id="navbar1"
data-target="#navbar2" with id="navbar2"
```

Also you should use the navbar-right class instead of pull-right. See [Navbar Alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment) for more info.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 110px;
}
div.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Computer Medic</a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-header -->
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Admin</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../../../database_code/database_code.php">Database Code</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="../../../projects/projects.php">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../../../bookmarks/bookmarks.php">Bookmarks</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../../../notes/notes.php">Notes</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- to enable navigation dropdown when viewed in mobile device -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Change "Site Admin" to your site name -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CM Site Admin</a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- highlight for order related pages -->
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <!-- highlight for user related pages -->
          <li>
            <a href="#">Users</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- options in the upper right corner of the page -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <!-- update currently logged in admin user -->
              <li>
                <a href="#">Edit Profile</a>
              </li>
              <!-- change password -->
              <li>
                <a href="#">Change Password</a>
              </li>
              <!-- log out user -->
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
    galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes that's it, that works, looks like I needed two separate nav bars.

Comment: Actually the iPhone one still overlaps - the number2 nav still calls the number1 nav on the small screen Shot?

Comment: I just tested it on an iPhone and it works as it should (individual toggling of each navbar): [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/teKuq). Check your code again the posted example again please.

Comment: I didn't change the body padding? Could that be it? And where are you putting that css?

Comment: All those rules to are A) remove any space between the navbars `margin-bottom: 0` B) `padding-top: 100px` ensures any content is not hidden under the navbars since they have a fixed position (these rules would go after your core Bootstrap CSS file, generally in a new stylesheet). Check the structure of the HTML against what you are using. Better yet copy my example and test that on a mobile device.

Comment: I copied your html over - my custom css loads after bootstrap.css and before my nav html. - works great on desktop and iPad but not on iPhone - I do have other css files loading before it as well.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you test this *independent* of anything else because I have no insight into your environment. Test it on it's own and see if it works or not please.

Comment: Ok, found the issue just need to resolve a link issue - looks like it might be a caching issue - seems to load old html code (is located in a separate include file) after a successful login, I'll figure it out. Thanks!